# Change live tile animation

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, live-tile

I am developing application for Windows Phone 8.1.

I have developed live tile for my app. I am trying to find a way to configure live tile change animation. By default I see kind of Flip animation. It looks a little annoying. I do want to change it.

So, how to configure live tile change animation?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change it, which in my eyes is the best choice for a consistent user experience and performance of the start screen.

Comment: I cannot believe in it. There are tiles with another animation. Do you think, that the only possible animation is "Flip"?